# Jquery .click not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to learn JQuery here, im starting off really simple.

When I click the button, the page reloads and nothing happens.

Heres my JS:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $("#submitShout").click(function() {  
  alert('hi');
  });  

  </script>
```

Here's my html:

```
<div class="panel right">   
<form name="shout" >
<textarea name="text" id="text" class="ribbitText"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submitShout" value="Ribbit!">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included the reference to jquery library?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: yes, updated code with full js

Answer (score 3):

i think you forgot document.ready..

```
$(function () { //<--- here..the codes below is called whn document is ready
    $("#submitShout").click(function () {
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

Comment: wow i feel dumb, how did i make such an amateur mistake.  thanks

Comment: hehe.. :)..  i know.. i think it is time for you to go for a coffee now.. :) :);)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include jQuery reference and you code surrounded with

```
$(function(){

});
```

as

```
$(function () {
    $("#submitShout").click(function () {
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

or click binded at the end of the document

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,

```
$("#submitShout").on("click", function() {  
  alert('hi');
});
```

If it is lower version Jquery, try this.

```
$("#submitShout").live("click", function() {  
      alert('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery 1.9 version**

```
$(function(){
    $("#submitShout").on('click',function(){
        //your code
        });
});
```

**jQuery version lower than 1.9**

```
$(function(){
     $("#submitShout").live('click',function(){
            //your code
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

that's a really old jquery version, upgrade it to something newer:

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Either you are missing the `doc ready` handler or the `jQuery lib`:

first try with this:

```
   $(function(){
     $("#submitShout").click(function() {  
         alert('hi');
      }); 
   });
```

then this one:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){
     $("#submitShout").click(function() {  
         alert('hi');
      }); 
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure jQuery is loaded
2. use the latest jQuery library
3. check the error console (using chrome developer tools or firebug for firefox
4. try changing your jQuery to

**code:**

```
$(function(){
    $("#submitShout").click(function(e) {  
       e.preventDefault();
       alert('hi');
       return false;
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#submitShout").click(function(event) {  
      alert('hi');
      event.preventDefault();
      });  
    });
      </script>
```